# How to mount azure-cloud drive?

Tags: c#, java, azure, azure-clouddrive

I want to mount vhd from my private container. After google I get that it is only possible through .net . I am more of a JAVA person. So I tried [this](http://mountvhdazurevm.codeplex.com/) code on visual studio 2012. But I keep getting exception `RoleEnvironment not available`. I don't know what it is please tell me how to set `RoleEnvironment`. Or please provide any other code which can mount my vhd.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate a lot of what you are trying to do using Azure Cmdlets:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152841

The Add-AzureDisk power shell command:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152837.aspx

...will allow you to add a data disk (VHD) to an existing Azure Iaas VM.

**For PaaS Worker Roles look at this:**
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/6cf7de11-45f2-47ae-b84e-708b67b15f72

Comment: I need a batch script or code in c# (So that I can get an exe file) which can automatically run at startup and mount vhd.

Comment: I have PaaS Worker Role, so I didn't think power shell is an option for me.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can override the start method in a worker/web role and attach a CloudDrive VHD dynamically.

Comment: In Worker role I Keep getting exception `ERROR_DEVFABRIC_LOCAL_MOUNT_ONLY` at

    `string driveLetter = drive.Mount(0, DriveMountOptions.Force);`

Where I did wrong?